# Can the defaultSearchField in a Solr schema be set to "any or all" fields?

Tags: schema, solr, default

There is a parameter in the Solr schema to set a default search field like so...

```
<!-- field for the QueryParser to use when an explicit fieldname is absent -->
<defaultSearchField>detail</defaultSearchField>
```

...But I would like to search all fields (I have five besides "detail") when the user does not specify.

How can I make search **all** fields the default behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "copy field" instructions to copy the content of all fields into a "catch all" field at index time. Use that field as the default search field.